# Cargar datos en una página web desde un archivo .json usando javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando una pagina web que contenga 6 tarjetas con la clase card, cuyos datos: imagen, nombre, marca, modelo, color y precio sean cargados desde el archivo 'productos.json' usando un script de JavaScript, sin embargo, la carga de los datos no se realiza,  así como tampoco la visualización de las tarjetas.

Por favor agradezco su orientación para lograr que los datos sean cargados y las tarjetas visualizadas correctamente. Muchas Gracias!:

Html5:

```
        <body>
                <div id="productosContainer" class="row"></div>
                <script src="./script.js"></script>
        </body>
```

JavaScript:

```
        fetch('./productos.json')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {

      const productosContainer = document.getElementById('productosContainer');

      if (Array.isArray(data)) { // Verificar si data es un arreglo
        data.productos.forEach(producto => {
          const card = document.createElement('div');
          card.classList.add('col-md-4', 'mb-4');
    
          const image = document.createElement('img');
          image.src = producto.imagen;
          image.classList.add('card-img-top');
    
          const card Body = document.createElement('div');
          cardBody.classList.add('card-body');
    
          const title = document.createElement('h5');
          title.classList.add('card title');
          title.textContent = producto. Nombre;
    
          const marca = document.createElement('p');
          marca.classList.add('card-text');
          marca.textContent = `Marca: ${producto. Marca}`;
    
          const modelo = document.createElement('p');
          modelo.classList.add('card-text');
          modelo.textContent = `Modelo: ${producto. Modelo}`;
    
          const color = document.createElement('p');
          color.classList.add('card-text');
          color.textContent = `Color: ${producto. Color}`;
    
          const precio = document.createElement('p');
          precio.classList.add('card-text');
          precio.textContent = `Precio: $${producto. Precio}`;

          productosContainer.appendChild(card);
          card.appendChild(card Body);

          card.appendChild(image);
          cardBody.appendChild(title);
          cardBody.appendChild(marca);
          cardBody.appendChild(modelo);
          cardBody.appendChild(color);
          cardBody.appendChild(precio);
        });
      } else {
        console.error('Error en el Tipo de Datos');
      }
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

.json:

```
        {
    "productos": [
      {
        "imagen": "./img/1.jpeg",
        "nombre": "Producto 1",
        "marca": "Marca 1",
        "modelo": "Modelo 1",
        "color": "Color 1",
        "precio": 10.99
      },
      {
        "imagen": "./img/2.jpeg",
        "nombre": "Producto 2",
        "marca": "Marca 2",
        "modelo": "Modelo 2",
        "color": "Color 2",
        "precio": 19.99
      },
      ........... 4 productos mas ...................
    ]
  }
```

Comment: En el código verificas que recibes un *array* ...  pero tu `JSON` es un **Objeto**, o, al menos, en lo poco que muestras se ve claramente un `}` al final.

Comment: De acuerdo con @Trauma. lo que debe ser un array es `data.productos`... no `data` solo

Answer (score 0):

He identificado diversas correcciones que debes realizar en tu código. A continuación, te proporciono el archivo con las correcciones de JavaScript. Más adelante, detallaré cada una de ellas:

```
fetch("./productos.json")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    const productosContainer = document.getElementById("productosContainer");

    if (Array.isArray(data.productos)) {
      data.productos.forEach((producto) => {
        const card = document.createElement("div");
        card.classList.add("col-md-4", "mb-4");

        const image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src = producto.imagen;
        image.classList.add("card-img-top");

        const cardBody = document.createElement("div");
        cardBody.classList.add("card-body");

        const title = document.createElement("h5");
        title.classList.add("card-title");
        title.textContent = producto.nombre;

        const marca = document.createElement("p");
        marca.classList.add("card-text");
        marca.textContent = `Marca: ${producto.marca}`;

        const modelo = document.createElement("p");
        modelo.classList.add("card-text");
        modelo.textContent = `Modelo: ${producto.modelo}`;

        const color = document.createElement("p");
        color.classList.add("card-text");
        color.textContent = `Color: ${producto.color}`;

        const precio = document.createElement("p");
        precio.classList.add("card-text");
        precio.textContent = `Precio: $${producto.precio}`;

        productosContainer.appendChild(card);
        card.appendChild(cardBody);

        card.appendChild(image);
        cardBody.appendChild(title);
        cardBody.appendChild(marca);
        cardBody.appendChild(modelo);
        cardBody.appendChild(color);
        cardBody.appendChild(precio);
      });
    } else {
      console.error("Error en el Tipo de Datos");
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

Correcciones:

1. La validación del JSON que recibes plantea un problema específico. En lugar de usar `Array.isArray(data)`, necesitas considerar que estás recibiendo un objeto con una propiedad que es tu arreglo. Por lo tanto, la validación adecuada sería la siguiente:

```
Array.isArray(data.productos)
```

2. Has cometido un error al crear la variable `card Body` usando un espacio en el nombre. No puedes declarar variables con espacios. La corrección adecuada sería:

```
const cardBody = document.createElement("div");
```

3. Has cometido un error al crear la clase `card title` usando un espacio en el nombre. No puedes declarar clases con espacios. La corrección adecuada sería:

```
title.classList.add("card-title");
```

4. Al crear tu JSON, has utilizado minúsculas para nombrar las variables. Sin embargo, al referirte a ellas en tu archivo JavaScript, las estás escribiendo con la primera letra en mayúscula y un espacio entre las palabras `(producto. Nombre, producto. Marca, producto. Modelo, producto. Color, producto. Precio)`. La corrección apropiada sería mantener la coherencia en la convención de nomenclatura que estás utilizando:

```
title.textContent = producto.nombre;
marca.textContent = `Marca: ${producto.marca}`;
modelo.textContent = `Modelo: ${producto.modelo}`;
color.textContent = `Color: ${producto.color}`;
precio.textContent = `Precio: $${producto.precio}`;
```

Comment: Buenos Días Sr Nicolás:
Agradezco su interés en dar oportuna y pertinente respuesta mi solicitud, solucionando los errores en los que he incurrido, con lo cual el proyecto funcionó cabalmente. Le reitero mi gratitud. Saludos!